# AudioManager.setStreamMute does not work independently for STREAM_RING and STREAM_NOTIFICATION?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-audiomanager

I am trying to mute a ringer while allowing notifications to sound and vice versa. In Eclipse, I'm watching the expressions window and am perplexed by the values I'm seeing and hoping anyone can shed some light on this:

```
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true); //notifications
Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Stream Notification Muted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);//mute ringer = off
Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Stream Ringer UN-Muted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In the expressions window, I'm watching the value of:

```
   amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) 
   amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
```

They start with both having a volume of 7. When `amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true)` executes, they BOTH move to 0.

Then, when `amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);` executes, they BOTH move to 7.

Can anyone shed any light on this?? I read that as of ICS the ringer and notification stream are now interlinked, but I'm seeing this when I'm using an emulator for API Level 10 as well.

Any ideas at all? Thanks in advance!